# Java - reference "to be resolved later"

Tags: java, arrays, reference, tree

Is there a way to define "pointers to pointers" in Java?

i.e. I'm thinking of something like this ...

```
class Main
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        Test[] test = new Test[20];

        Test t = test[10];

        test[10] = new Test(7);

        System.out.println(t.whatever);
    }
}

class Test{
    public Test(int i){this.whatever = i;}
    Integer whatever;
}
```

This obviously produces a nullptr exception in Java. How can I keep t updated, instead?

I.e. if this were C, I would probably write it somewhat like this:

```
typedef struct{
    int whatever;
} Test;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Test *test = malloc(sizeof(*test) * 20);
    Test *t = &test[10];

    test[10].whatever = 7;
    printf("%d\n",t->whatever);

    return 0;
}
```

The reason I'm considering something like this at all is that I'm trying to parse a tree from file where the children to each node are given by an array of nodeIDs only.

It would be convenient if I could ignore the fact that a child may or may not have been parsed, already, and just point to an array entry (index corresponding to child's nodeID), thereby forgoing the need to traverse all nodes again later just to insert child pointers.

I thought about creating an array of wrapper instances, instead, and use references to them. Can I do better?

Comment: java doesn´t have pointers like `C` does, so no you can´t. but you could initialize `test[10]` first and make `t` refer to the same instance of `Test`. But you cannot go to a level where a reassignment of `t` would also reflect to a change of `test[10]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to parse a tree from file where the children to each node are given by an array of node IDs only.

You can do it with [`Supplier<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html), an interface whose implementations are capable of producing `T` on demand:

```
final Test[] test = new Test[20];
Supplier<Test> t = () -> test[10];
test[10] = new Test(7);
System.out.println(t.get().whatever); // Prints 7
test[10] = new Test(42);
System.out.println(t.get().whatever); // Prints 42
```

[Demo 1.](http://ideone.com/58IEid)

If you do not have access to Java-8, here is an implementation that uses an interface and an anonymous class instead:

```
interface ForwardTest {
    Test get();
}

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        final Test[] test = new Test[20];
        ForwardTest t = new ForwardTest() {public Test get() {return test[10];} };
        test[10] = new Test(7);
        System.out.println(t.get().whatever);
    }
}

class Test {
    public Test(int i){this.whatever = i;}
    Integer whatever;
}
```

[Demo 2.](http://ideone.com/Liork9)

Answer (score 2):

No unfortunately this cannot work in java simply because pointers don't exist in java, the only way is to use Object wrapper like `AtomicReference` for example.

**NB:** `AtomicReference` is not meant to be used for this kind of need as it is based on a `volatile` variable which is not necessary in your case but it is the idea.